# Infopath 2010 browser enabled form columns export into excel spreadsheet?

Tags: infopath

I have a infopath 2010 browser enabled form which i have submitted to Document Library.I have to export number of columns of form into excel sheet.
Now, i am able to use Export To Excel option available in sharepoint 2010,but in this case i am getting all columns available in.
I want to export specific columns into excel sheet.
Please suggest any approach in sharepoint or any Out Of Box functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating a different view inside the document library. On this new view you can select only the columns you want to export.

Just go to the SharePoint libary, click on "Library" and then "Modify this View" or "Create new View".

I hope it helps.